# Using Webcam with Android emulator when running OpenCV sample for Face Detection

Tags: android, opencv, android-emulator, android-camera, face-detection

I was trying to configure Open CV on Android.After following this tutorial 
     ->http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html
     ->http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#android-dev-intro
I have set the libraries well and no error. When i launch the Open CV samples 'FaceDetection',it kept showing an error on the emulator like
          "It seems that your device does not support camera(or its locked). Application will be closed". 
When i create the emulator i have set it to have a camera support(not both sides only front camera is set to work and uses the web cam to capture a frame). Open CV manager is successfully configured on the emulator. Is there any possibility that my device doesn't support camera? !! How do i unlock the camera? !! 
Thanks.
P.S I am using Eclipse IDE(Juno) with latest ADT(Android 4.2.2 -  API level 17), CDT and NDK configured. I am also using Opencv 2.4.4 android sdk. The Android emulator device is 10.1" WXGA tablet.Have no specific reason to use this device(I just picked it from the list because it's camera works). I am using the back camera with the web cam and none of the front camera.

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to docs on Android for open cv on open cv's website i have come to discover that there is a little chance to use the emulator camera because some samples use Android Java Camera API, which is accessible with an AVD. But most of samples use OpenCV Native Camera which may not work with an emulator.   http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#running-opencv-samples

Regards